# Setup an IIS self signed certificate on Oracle Application Server

Tags: ssl, asp.net, https, windows, certificate

My main server is running IIS 7 and has an ASP.NET/C# website that needs communicate to another server that uses Oracle Application Server.

Currently, the website is communicating to the Oracle Applicatoin Server using HTTP. I would like to setup the SSL certificate so that I can access the Oracle Application Server via HTTPS from the website.

Do I just need to create the self signed certificate on IIS 7 then export it and set it up on the Oracle Application Server?

Comment: Do you also need external access to this application running on this application server. Or is it only for internal use?

Comment: Just need access between these two servers. They're at different data centers, and the oracle server can only be accessed via HTTP.

Comment: That's different than what you said before. You said before that it only can be accessed using HTTPS? Can you clarify that?

Comment: Sorry, I meant that I would like to setup the certificate so that I can access it using HTTPS. Currently, it's being accessed using HTTP by an ASP.NET website. I updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

You have three options I think

1. Creating your own certificate server. That's quite a lot of work, but it maybe worth the work If you need to deploy more certificates in the future.
2. Generating a self signed certificate. See here for more information:[Create a Self-Signed Server Certificate in IIS 7](http://technet.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/cc753127%28WS.10%29.aspx)
3. Buying an certificate from a certificate provider.

In this scenario you can try first with a self signed certificate, It that doesn't work, or doesn't fulfill your need you can always go with option 1 or option 3.

What I personally don't know is what requirements Oracle has for a certificate of their application server. After some research I found out that you probably have to submit a request a to a certificate authority (CA), which excludes option 2 for you then. See here for you reference:
[13 Overview of Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) in Oracle Application Server](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B14099_19/core.1012/b13995/ssl_intro.htm)